# Transitive Conditional Probability Constraints

Tags: probability

Is there a nice rule describing how the values of $P(C|B)$ and $P(B|A)$ jointly constrain $P(C|A)$? In particular, if I know that both $P(C|B)$ and $P(B|A)$ are above some threshold value $t$, what does that tell us about $P(C|A)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot conclude anything about $P(C|A)$, it can still be $0$. For example, if 
I am rolling a $6$ sided die and the events $A,B,C$ are

- $A$... I roll an odd number
- $B$... I roll a number between $1$ and $6$
- $C$... I roll an even number

Then $P(C|B)=\frac12, P(B|A)=1$ (they are above the threshold $t=\frac12$), however $P(C|A)=0$.

There is also no upper bound, since you can replace $A$ above with "rolling an even number",a nd $P(C|A($ is then $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer!

Comment: although i just wanted to check, is $P(C|A)$ unconstrained even when $P(B|A)$ and $P(C|B)$ are both 0.99, for example? Surely not, right?

Comment: @KingKong Roll a $n$-sided die. Then let $A$ be "I roll a $1$", and let $C$ be "I roll a number greater than $1$". Also, let $B$ be "I roll any number". Then, $P(B|A)=1, P(C|B)=\frac{n-1}{n}$, and $P(C|A)=0$.

Comment: ah, of course! Thanks :-)

Comment: @KingKong This is actually something people outside of mathematics should know about. Even if $C$ is very probable given $B$, and $B$ is very probable given $A$, we don't (without further assumptions or measurments) have **any idea** about how probable $C$ is given $A$. A real world example would be that if the sky is clear, it's very likely I will be sunburnt, and if I see the stars, it's very likely that the sky is clear. However, if I see the stars, then it is not likely at all that I will get sunburnt.

Comment: Right, it's a really interesting point. I had previously noticed that correlation is not transitive, but i didn't realise how radically non-transitive probabilistic confirmation can be.